# tags underneath headings disappear when clicked again w/ javascript no idea why

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have pasted the javascript below but also a link to my codepen so you can see exactly what I am talking about.

I would like the heading to be clicked and expose the text below.  On another click I would like for the text to go back to hidden.  Multiple headings can be opened at the same time. What is happening with my current setup is you can click once to show, click again to hide and then when you click again to show nothing shows, if you keep clicking the text and headings below are eaten/dissapear.  I would prefer to do this without jquery.  thanks for any help.

http://codepen.io/jrutishauser/pen/YPrrNa

```
 var clickToShow = function () { 
          if (this.nextElementSibling.className === 'open'){
                  this.nextElementSibling.remove('open');
          } else if (this.nextElementSibling.className != 'open') { 
          this.nextElementSibling.className = 'open';
          } 
  }; 

  var articleHeadings = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

 for (var index = 0; index < articleHeadings.length; index++){
         articleHeadings[index].onclick = clickToShow;
 }

 var subArticleHeadings = document.getElementsByTagName('h4');

 for (var index2 = 0; index2 < subArticleHeadings.length; index2++){
         subArticleHeadings[index2].onclick = clickToShow;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `this.nextElementSibling.remove('open')` to `this.nextElementSibling.className = ''`. I believe remove() method removes the element, not the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this also. This is the correct way of doing it.

```
var clickToShow = function () { 
      element=this.nextElementSibling;
          if (element.className === 'open'){
              element.className=element.className.replace('open','');
          } else if (element.className != 'open') { 
          element.className = 'open';
          } 
  };
```

Comment: just googled this and read about it.  I can see the value, thanks for the follow up